# Unable to set bind variables for view object of ADF trees

Tags: oracle-adf

I am having an ADF tree made from the TreeVO containing two attributes Parent_prod and Prod. This VO has a view link joining it to itself. TreeVo also has named bind variables which I need to set at run time through my managed bean. I am using the following code to set it -

```
ViewObject vo = am.findViewObject("Tree_VO1");
VariableValueManager vm = vo.ensureVariableManager();
vm.setVariableValue("a", "Oracle Sales Catalog");
vm.setVariableValue("b",selectedRow.getAttribute("Pillar"));
vm.setVariableValue("c",selectedRow.getAttribute("ProductLine"));
vm.setVariableValue("d", selectedRow.getAttribute("ProductGroup"));
vo.executeQuery();
```

But at run time through the logs ( set to FINEST), I get that bind variables are not getting set and it is taking Null values for them.

Answer (score 2):

Tree binding uses accessors for it's hierarchy child. Therefore your bind variable only get applied to top parent view object.
To pass it to the child instances you need to override ViewObject's method `createViewLinkAccessorRS` and then reapply your variables there, something like this:

```
`@Override
protected ViewRowSetImpl createViewLinkAccessorRS(AssociationDefImpl associationDefImpl, ViewObjectImpl viewObjectImpl, Row row, Object[] object){
  ViewRowSetImpl vrs = super.createViewLinkAccessorRS(associationDefImpl, viewObjectImpl, row, object);

  //Apply variable from parent view object to its leaf
  viewObjectImpl.getVariableManager().setVariableValue("variable_name", getVariableManager().getVariableValue("variable_name"));
  return vrs;
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course bind variables are not getting set because you are presuming that an adf tree will use the view object instance, which is incorrect. An adf tree is  using view accessors.

Since you are already constructing the tree programatically, makes little sense to use ADF BC, therefore you may be better of with a programmatic POJO-based tree like here: http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.hu/2007/05/back-to-programming-programmatic-adf.html